# PHP zipArchive::setPassword not working properly

Tags: php, passwords, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a zip file protected with password.
It has two files inside, fileA.php (size=1KB) and fileB.php (size=4KB).

When I execute this code:

```
        $mipass="xxx";
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if ($zip->open("myzipfile.zip") === true) {
            if ($zip->setPassword($mipass)) {
                $zip->extractTo("test");
                $zip->close();
               echo 1;
            } else {
                echo 0;
            }
        }
```

It prints 1, the "test" folder is created but the code have only extracted fileA.php and it has a size of 0KB.

The php version of my local server is 5.6.24

Comment: can you extract the file per "hand" with your password ? maybe the zip is corrupt

Comment: Yes, the file has been created by me and I've check it. Also, if try to extract a zip file without password the code works well.

Comment: what kind of encryption do you use to generate zip -file? aes-256 seems not to be supported, if i use a zip created by zip-crypto i can decrypt it by your script

Comment: could be that, I created the zip file using WinRar which seems to use aes-256... thanks!